# I recently got my iPhone 4 unlocked from att I have some issues and want to erase and rest all setings, can this effect my unlocked status?

Tags: iphone

I recently got my iPhone 4 unlocked from att I have some issues from before the unlock that persist (microphone, home button, internet connections).

I did not have to restore or set up the iPhone as new, as soon as the unlocked message appeared in iTunes I disconnected the phone, there were no resulting problems but I still have the problems from before the unlock.

I simply did not restore or set up the phone as new because I did not want to loose all my data,  my phone is jailbroken and before the unlock I was using a gevey sim.

I want to erase and rest all setings, to start fresh, can this effect my unlocked status?
I don't want to loose my unlock as I live in Costa Rica 
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

If the phone was unlocked 'legally' (as is true in your case) then factory resetting will not affect the unlock status.